# escape key keystroke to exit

Tags: javascript, html

How to exit from full screen iframe by escape key so that iframe gets back into its originalsize. Please suggest me javascript code for this as jquery is not working in html page.

Here is the code for fullscreen iframe.

```
<iframe name='myiframe2' id='frame2' src=http://stackoverflow.com' style='position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:999' frameborder='no'></iframe>
```

Comment: Please do not have 2 identical questions open at the same time - also you have a quote too little in the above. What triggers the iframe size?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this (you cannot frame stackoverflow btw)?

```
<iframe name="myiframe1" id="frame1" src="javascript:'hello 1'" 
style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:999" frameborder="no"></iframe>
<iframe name="myiframe2" id="frame2" src="javascript:'hello 2'" 
style="display:none;width:300px;height:300px" frameborder="yes"></iframe>
<script>
document.onkeypress=document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;
  var kc = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
  if (kc==27) {
    document.getElementById('frame2').style.display=''
    document.getElementById('frame1').style.display='none'
  } 
}
</script>
```